# How to setup https ssl on tomcat server by wildcard certification?

Tags: linux, ssl, certificate, https, tomcat

I'm trying to setup https://my.example.com to access Tomcat web linux server.

The first step, I trying to use 'keytool' to generate one, it works, but the browser will show red lock icon(I try https://192.168.1.2):

```
rm keystore.jks 
keytool -keystore keystore.jks \           
   -storepass PASS -alias tomcat -genkeypair -validity 730 \             
   -sigalg SHA256withRSA -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -dname 'CN=my' \    
   -keypass PASS
```

Now, I trying to setup by wildcard certification file (example.com.pfx) that let other Windows based server workable(eg. https://www.example.com).

```
rm keystore.jks 
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore example.com.pfx \
    -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore keystore.jks -deststoretype JKS
```

In this Linux machine, I still haven't setup DNS, but use local /etc/hosts file.

```
192.168.1.2 my my.example.com
```

In my browser(chromium), I try https://192.168.1.2, now it can not work with the converted key. The error message was ERR_TIMED_OUT.

After setup browser side (windows /system32/drivers/etc/hosts), I try the "https://my.example.com". It still got timeout.

Comment: Check that Tomcat is running, started after the keystore change, and is listening on 443; if not look at its log(s).

Answer (score 0):

SSL certificate issued to work with `*.example.com` will work for all URLs that satisfy `https://*.example.com`

`https://192.168.1.2` does not satisfy `*.example.com` so it won't work for this.

As per `192.168.1.2 my my.example.com` HOSTS change only `https://my.example.com` will work.

Comment: Do you mean I should setup DNS anyway?